# How do I make an NIC on my cluster dedicated to a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, cluster-computing, vmware, vsphere

We have a number of VMs running on a cluster that we access via vSphere. We wish to add an extra NIC that a VM can use but we only wish for that to have access to it. No other VMs should be allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. Add a NIC to all hosts you want the target vm to be movable to (vMotion).
2. bind the NIC(s) to a new vswitch or dvswitch and create a new network.
3. in the vm settings, choose the new network for the vNIC of the vm.
4. that should do the trick.

keep in mind that you'l need the new network available on all hosts you want the vm to be moveable to. otherwise your vm will only run on the hosts you added the network to.

hope that helps.